# C++ How to do timer?

Tags: c++, mbed

I am working on embedded systems using `mbed.h`. I want to increase the counter variable every time the button is pressed in 60 seconds, so I have to create a timer and count the number of times the button is pressed in 60 seconds.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "time.h"

DigitalOut user_led(PA_5);
Ticker t;

void toggleLED(){
    user_led =! user_led;

}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    clock t = new clock();
    while (true){
        if (user_led){
            counter += 1;
            t.attach(&toggleLED ,1s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help you solve your problem: [https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.16/apis/timeout.html](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.16/apis/timeout.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is an updated version of the code you have provided which will do what you want.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "time.h"

DigitalOut user_led(PA_5);
InterruptIn button(USER_BUTTON);
Ticker ticker;
void toggleLED() {
    user_led = !user_led;
}
int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    time_t start_time = time(NULL);
    ticker.attach(&toggleLED, 1s);
    button.fall([&]() {
        time_t current_time = time(NULL);
        if (difftime(current_time, start_time) <= 60) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
            start_time = current_time;
        }
    });
    while (true) {
        //while true do nothing
    }
}
```